# InDesign: how to adjust table spacing

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting, tables, formatting, white-space

Is there a way to define how big the distance betweeen text and table grids in InDesign is? Right now my table looks kind of crammed with the text so close to its cell borders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to study this part of the ID interface, especially the "Cell Height" (which forces your rows to be taller) and "Top/Bottom Cell Insets" (same result, but by increasing inside cell margins) on the right side. There's also a lot of Youtube content on this.

[image]

Comment: Table Insets was what I was looking for. Thank you so much! You're my InDesign-Hero lol :D

Comment: If you're wondering how to get the table-formatting controls because neither using the selection- nor the type- tool shows it: mark at least two cells and the toolbar appears.

Comment: Window --> Type & Tables --> Table (Or just SHIFT + F9)

Answer (score 0):

To show the toolbar, you can also hover your Text cursor along the top of a table until it becomes a downward arrow, and then left click.